# Simple Checkbox with a Cross Instead of Tick

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a checkbox but I have no idea how to make it with a cross (X) instead of the tick. Any idea how I can edit this??

Here's my current working code...

```css
.checkbox {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.checkbox label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.checkbox label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.checkbox label::after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #555555;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f00c";
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca;
}
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d9534f;
}
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    border-color: #5bc0de;
}
.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
    border-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #5cb85c;
}
.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
.radio {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.radio label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.radio label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.radio label::after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 3px;
    top: 3px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #555555;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
    transition: transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
}
.radio input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:focus + label::before {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled + label::before {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.radio.radio-inline {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.radio-primary input[type="radio"] + label::after {
    background-color: #428bca;
}
.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #428bca;
}
.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #428bca;
}
.radio-danger input[type="radio"] + label::after {
    background-color: #d9534f;
}
.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #d9534f;
}
.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #d9534f;
}
.radio-info input[type="radio"] + label::after {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #5bc0de;
}
.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.radio-warning input[type="radio"] + label::after {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.radio-success input[type="radio"] + label::after {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #5cb85c;
}
.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Checkboxes</h2>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
                        <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" checked="">
                        <label for="checkbox6">
                            Check me out
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your understanding of the code that you already have?  (Did you copy it from somewhere else?)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Change content `content: "\f00d";` to `.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after` class.

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

Comment: I wanted something like a class. for example class "error-checkbox"

Comment: Please check I have added css , find in your css file and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `content:"\f00d"` into `.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after`

or add add other class for that like you suggested

```
.checkbox.error-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after  {
    content: "\f00d";
}
```

```css
.checkbox {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.checkbox label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.checkbox label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.checkbox label::after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f00c";
}
.checkbox.error-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after  {
    content: "\f00d";
}
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d9534f;
}
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Checkboxes</h2>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <fieldset>                  
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger error-checkbox">
                        <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" checked="">
                        <label for="checkbox6">
                            Check me out
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you give the code to add that style instead of substitute?

Comment: I wanted something like a class. for example class "error-checkbox"

Comment: I have added class and css for that.. update my answer